# Linked List Insertion in the middle

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, insertion

```
Node InsertNth(Node head, int data, int position) {


    Node start,curr,temp;
    start=head;
    curr=start;
    if(start==null)
        {
        temp=new Node();
        temp.data=data;
        temp.next=null;
        return head;
    }
    else if(position==0)
        {
        temp=new Node();
        temp.data=data;
        temp.next=start;
        return head;
    }
    else
        {
        for(int i=0;i<position;i++)
            {
            System.out.println("i:"+i);
            curr=start;
            start=start.next;
        }
        temp=new Node();
        temp.data=data;
        curr.next=temp;
        temp.next=start;
        return head;
    } 
}
```

In the above code I printed the value of "i" in the for-loop.
In the console I am getting the output as

```
i:0
i:0
i:1
i:0
i:1
i:2
i:3
```

And

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Node.InsertNth(Solution.java:49)
    at Solution.main(Solution.java:88)
```

Why is "i" not incrementing properly? If it does work well then I can perform insertion in middle.

Comment: You need to check if position < length of list..

Comment: Ok! I will keep start!=null  condition. But, I keep getting the same "i" values. Why i values are not incrementing properly.

Comment: What value did you pass as position?

Comment: What's your 49'th line?

Comment: Thats what I am not getting. I am doing this in Hackerrank website. The Function takes positon as an integer argument. Thats what he mentioned.

Comment: It does not make any difference, as my curr.next is start. I kept that, no change. The problem is in the loop, when I print the values here is the output 

I tried to print the values of the position .The position value is also changing in the loop by itself.

Comment: Right, didn't notice, anyway, what's your 49'th line? Did you try printing the position values? What's the output?

Comment: Position values in the loop are like 1,2,2,4,4,4,1

Comment: There is no 49th line actually. When I added start!=null condition, the error is not thrown. The output is incorrect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84605/discussion-between-saiteja-reddy-and-mouseevent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why is `return head;` in your first two cases? `temp` is the new head of the list and should be returned instead.

Second, **your loop is correct**. However, Hackerrank *runs multiple test cases*. I typed up a solution and inserted newlines at the beginning of the method call. You simply have three test cases executing.

```
i: 0

i: 0
i: 1

i: 0
i: 1
i: 2
i: 3
```

---

#### Improvements

1. You'll always have to create a new Node, so refactor that to make your code cleaner.
2. You don't need the `start == null` check, since you'll just append the old head (which may be `null`) to the end whenever `position == 0`.

With the improvements inserted:

```
Node InsertNth(Node head, int data, int position) {
    Node temp = new Node();
    temp.data = data;
    Node start = head;
    Node curr = start;
    if (position == 0)
    {
        temp.next = start;
        return temp;
    } 
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < position; i++)
        {
            curr=start;
            start=start.next;
        }
        curr.next=temp;
        temp.next=start;
        return head;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy. I realized what mistake I did.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with `for` loop, the problem is : **the method is called 3 times**

I just changed part of your code to :

```
else
{
    int count =0;
    for(int i=0;i<position;i++)
        {
        try{
        System.out.println("i :" +i);
        curr=start;
        start=start.next;
            count++;
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
    System.out.println("count: " +count);

    temp=new Node();
    temp.data=data;
    curr.next=temp;
    temp.next=start;
    return head;
}
```

and submitted in hackerrank and it prints :

```
i :0
count: 1
i :0
i :1
count: 2
i :0
i :1
i :2
i :3
count: 3
```

It is printing

```
    System.out.println("count: " +count);
```

3 times means your method is called thrice, not once as you are thinking.

Coming to writing the correct code, Just make sure that `start` is not null in for loop. I did not make try to change your code but just added what is necessary to make it work.

```
Node InsertNth(Node head, int data, int position) {
     Node start,curr,temp;
     start=head;
     curr=start;
     if(start==null || position == 0)
     {
        temp=new Node();
        temp.data=data;
        temp.next=start;
        head=temp;
        return head;
     }
     else
    {
        for(int i=0;i<position && start!=null ;i++)
        {
         curr=start;
         start=start.next;
        }
        temp=new Node();
        temp.data=data;
        curr.next=temp;
        temp.next=start;
        return head;
    } 
 }
```

Comment: I'd like to get some recognition for this answer, as I solved it in the chat.

Comment: Sorry If you are thinking that I did this after looking at your chat, your chat you are mistaken. You can verify the timings if you want. I posted this at `00:01` and your chat says `00:00`.`I guess you are not thinking that I copied your idea and changed the code and submitted in hackerrank and then wrote  an answer here` in one minute.